# When setting height of img with vp it affects sibling element width but with % it does not, why?

Tags: css, responsive-design

So if I set the height prop on img with vp, h2 (sibling element) has line breaks with respect to the img width (hence which is what I want). But if I set the image height with %, the h2 takes up as much width needed.

Really confused at what vp is doing other than setting image size relative to the browser.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  height: 30vh;
}
```

JSFiddle Link

https://jsfiddle.net/bqdxze94/9/

Comment: The width of the flex element parent determines how wide your h2 elements are, not the width of the image. The `vh` unit is based on the viewport height, whereas the height in percentage refers to the containing block's height, so two very different things.

Comment: okay i understand. But thats my point exactly. I'm confused as to why when vh set, the width of the h2 element is small. but when % set, the width of h2 takes up all width. Because it shouldn't be the image that sets the width of h2, but the parent.... thats exactly why i'm confused.

Comment: The `.single-container` elements are all 33% wide by default, because their parent is a flex container. The h2 elements simply follow the width those parents give them. The image element's _width_, which since not otherwise specified is related to the height you _do_ specify, by the image's intrinsic aspect ratio, can however stretch those parent containers to go beyond the 33% implied default width (and then themselves make their parent go beyond 100%.) _How_ you get those images to go wider, whether that is due to a height set in `vh` or `%`, does not make a difference in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe - Except that the .single-container elements are not 33% wide in Firefox.

Comment: @Alohci sorry, checked in a Chromium-based browser only ... what's happening in FF then?

Comment: @CBroe - it looks like the flex items are taking their width based on the full, intinsic size of the image. The image is then scaled down accordingly, but the flex item width is not further adjusted.

Comment: @Alohci yeah I see what you mean, with the percentage it behaves unexpectedly. Not sure what exactly formatting the images by height rather than giving them a full container width is supposed to achieve in that kind of construct to begin with though, if that's supposed to implement any kind of responsive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work:

**Solution:** `display: table; width: 0;`

*Note: I added some space around each item and made the second image bigger to show the behaviour*

[View StackBlitz :D](https://jsfiddle.net/bqdxze94/18/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  height: 30vh;
}

.img2 {
  height: 60vh;
}

.single-container {
  display: table;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="single-container">
    <img class="img2" src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.... kevin wow.... that display table width 0 is exactly what i'm looking for! now trying to figure out how that works... because everybody was saying set the parent container a width but man... that doesn't make it responsive because the image can be anything!!!!! this is perfect man. just trying to see why and how this works :) thanks brotha wow

Comment: Kevin, man something interesting, I noticed if the container is not flex, then the solution you showed me doesn't work. Why does the parent flex make the text inside h2 line break but when parent block, or no parent at all, the text inside h2 just take up max width.

Comment: hmm I believe its to do with the `flex-grow` css attribute in combination of the `table`. So the `display: table` enforces its min width, but the `flex-grow` being default value of `0`, prevents it from getting wider from the text.

Comment: A table will always like to expand based on the content that is inside it, unless told not too. So in this scenario its trying to expand and trying not to expand at the same time. xD

Comment: is there a scenario where you do not want a flex-box ?